# расширение textarea при вводе текста и сужение при удаление

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if(this.scrollTop > 0) {
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea class='send-textarea' style="overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```

Он работает, не могли бы вы помочь сделать чтобы при удаление текста, textarea возвращался в исходный размер? приму на любом языке ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так попробовать

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('input', autoResize, false);
function autoResize() {

  this.style.height = 'auto';

  this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';

}
```

```html
<textarea class='send-textarea' style="overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! :)